# Android phonegap application goes blank

Tags: android, html, cordova

I am developing a android phonegap application. I am facing strange issue on my Asus tab (android version 4.3). If I go to home screen of the phone when the app is running and then open my app from  running apps, I get a blank white screen. The text and images appears when I tap on the screen. Issue is only on Asus andoird 4.3. I tried same thing on a galaxy note3 neo android version 4.4.2 and it works fine (on returning to the app from recently opened apps, the app loads correctly).

What can be the issue?

Comment: did you get any error in Log cat?

Comment: Might be the issue is related to the Web View engine of Asus. Now a days Chromium Web engines are better for css. Also try connecting the Asus tab to your chrome browser and inspect the phonegap app.

Comment: @Amy the issue is on the hand held device and not on the emulator

Comment: @SSS how can I connect my app to chrome browser?

Comment: just try to following SSS suggestion

Comment: Looks some code issue...specially in case you are manipulating the DOM.

Comment: @Arti Connect your device to your machine. Open Chrome Browser. and type in chrome://inspect/#devices
This will give you a list of connected devices. (Please enable debugging options on the Asus Tab and Save RSA key if asked to save.
Then open your phonegap application. Then check the browser for the device list. It will now have your application with inspect option.

Comment: @Arti Also try other devices of 4.3.